# Where can I download the RIM Blackberry 6.0 SDK?

Tags: blackberry, sdk

Where can I download the RIM Blackberry 6.0 SDK?

Answer (score 2):

It is not yet available.

http://supportforums.blackberry.com/t5/Java-Development/BB-SDK-6-0/m-p/490071

Comment: Hi John Rudy,

Thanks for your quick reply. I need one  more info. I have developed few apps which is complied in 4.6 , 4.7 and 5.0. Can any of these build will work on Blackberry 6.0 OS version or do i have to compile my app on 6.0 also ?

Comment: I don't develop on the Blackberry, I only did a google search and it turned up this 3 days old article. You should seek some answer on the blackberry forum.

Comment: I think nobody (at least outside RIM) knows yet as it officially doesn't exist yet. However AFAIK RIM OS versions usually forward compatible i.e. application build under SDK X will somehow run on OS Y if Y >= X. Sometimes old application runs not perfectly on newer OS versions (like pre-touch applications on newer devices) but it should run.

Comment: Saravan - BB has said that they are working to preserve 100% backward compatibility though, so it is probably safe to assume that you'll be OK -- though obviously you'll need to test once it's actually released.